# Google Sheets Dragfill isn't properly calculating based on highlighted cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, autofill

[image]

This is what the formulas look like correctly.

Cell B2    `=SUM(Daily!B2:B6)`
Cell B3    `=SUM(Daily!B7:B11)`
Cell B4    `=SUM(Daily!B12:B16)`

When I highlight those 3 cells and drag down I expect Cell B5 formula to fill as `=SUM(Daily!B17:B21)`

Instead dragging down makes it populate as   `=SUM(Daily!B5:B9)`

[image]

How do I fix this so I can drag fill that column?

Also sorry if I didn't post this correct way. First time here.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new dynamic array formulas to get results automatically. Try-

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(100,1,2,5),SEQUENCE(100,1,6,5),LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(INDEX(Daily!B:B,x):INDEX(Daily!B:B,y))))
```

Comment: @ChristianTaylor Did it work? If works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `OFFSET`.

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNT(Daily!B2:B)/5),1,0,5),LAMBDA(_,SUM(OFFSET(Daily!B2:B6,_,))))
```